# Is the entire row logged when an UPDATE statement is executed?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to estimate the logging impact of an UPDATE statement that changes one column on a few hundred thousand rows.  Does the entire row get logged, or just the one column?

I know that this can be done in batches with log backups running to keep the log size under control, but the crux of question is whether that will need to be done or not.

Comment: Huge *it depends* based on what is going to happen to the actual pages. Sometimes it is cheaper to take a before/after snapshot, sometimes it's cheaper per change. I'd test with a dataset that's actually representative of your real world dat set (i.e. a backup of production) and investigate the generated log.

Comment: Thanks @SeanGallardy.  I'm already quite sure for the issue at hand that we'll be OK as it is changing less than 1% of a 24 GB table, and I've got 44 GB free on my log drive.  So I don't really <i>need</i> to know, but I just thought it would be a good thing to know.  If the answer is "it depends," well, that's good to know also!

Comment: It'd be a good blog post :)